# How to apply a verb to every item in an AppleScript reference? (Specifically, Microsoft Excel)

Tags: applescript

In Microsoft Excel, I'm trying to use AppleScript to hide a bunch of rows that match a simple query: **if the value of column F is 0.0**. I have it working, but the script has to loop through each match to hide it, which is slower – and less elegant – than I'd like:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell used range of active sheet of active workbook
        set row_references to ((every row whose value of cell 6 is 0.0))
        repeat with current_row in row_references
            set hidden of entire row of current_row to true
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

What I would *really* like, is if I could hide each row just using one Apple Event:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell used range of active sheet of active workbook
        set hidden of (entire row of (every row whose value of cell 6 is 0.0)) to true
    end tell
end tell
```

… but this throws an error: "Can’t set hidden of entire row of every row of used range of active sheet of active workbook whose value of cell 6 = 0.0 to true."

If I used the "delete" verb, I can do something close to what I'm after:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell used range of active sheet of active workbook
        delete (every row whose value of cell 6 is 0.0)
    end tell
end tell
```

This just deletes every matching row in one fell swoop, no looping required.

(Note that I had to use the "entire row" reference in the first two examples, because the "hidden" property will only work if you specify an entire row or column as a range. The delete command doesn't have this requirement.)

So my question is: is what I'm trying to do even possible? Why does the "delete" verb work with no problems, but it doesn't seem to like "set"?

Thanks.

Comment: Some apps are better than others at evaluating complex queries. Word and Excel are at the not-so-good end. I think you'll probably just have to live with the loop.

Comment: Interesting, and makes sense. Thanks for the response @foo, it's nice to know that I wasn't just missing something obvious.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but what fails uses  (entire...) and the working one uses (every...).  Perhaps those two statements return different object types.